# Recurrent HTTP Error 413 when scraping multiple pages

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, runtime-error

I'm scraping posts off Wykop.pl ('Poland's Reddit') by looping through multiple pages that were returned when I searched for my keyword of interest on the site. I wrote a loop to iterate for my target content for each page; however the loop will terminate at certain pages (consistently) with the error 'HTTP Error 413: Request Entity Too Large'.

I tried to scrape the problematic pages individually, but the same error message kept recurring. To work around this I've had to set my ranges manually to collect the data, but at the cost of missing out on broad swath of data, and I would like to know if there is a Pythonic solution to deal with this error. I also tried longer pauses as perhaps maybe I was running the risk of sending too many requests, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

```
from time import sleep
from random import randint
import requests
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from mtranslate import translate
from IPython.core.display import clear_output


from mtranslate import translate
posts = []
votes = []
dates = []
images = []
users = []

start_time = time()
requests = 0
pages = [str(i) for i in range(1,10)]

for page in pages:
    url = "https://www.wykop.pl/szukaj/wpisy/smog/strona/" + page + "/"
    response = get(url)

    # Pause the loop
    sleep(randint(8,15))

        # Monitor the requests
    requests += 1
    elapsed_time = time() - start_time
    print('Request:{}; Frequency: {} requests/s'.format(requests, requests/elapsed_time))
    clear_output(wait = True)
    # Throw a warning for non-200 status codes
    if response.status_code != 200:
        warn('Request: {}; Status code: {}'.format(requests, response.status_code))
    # Break the loop if the number of requests is greater than expected
    if requests > 10:
        warn('Number of requests was greater than expected.')
        break


    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    results = soup.find_all('li', class_="entry iC")


    for result in results:
            # Error handling
            try:

                post = result.find('div', class_="text").text
                post = translate(post,'en','auto')
                posts.append(post)

                date = result.time['title']
                dates.append(date)

                vote = result.p.b.span.text
                vote = int(vote)
                votes.append(vote)

                user = result.div.b.text
                users.append(user)

                image = result.find('img',class_='block lazy')
                images.append(image)

            except AttributeError as e:
                print(e)
```

If I could run the script all at once, I would set the range from 1 to 163 (since I've got 163 pages worth of results of posts mentioning my keyword of interest). Thus I've had to set smaller ranges to collect the data incrementally, but again at the cost of missing out on pages of data.

An alternative I've as a contingency is to scrape from the designated problematic pages as downloaded html documents on my Desktop.

Comment: Missing BS4 import, friend! It is possible that you just made a mistake on pasting..

Comment: Also! memory leakage is a very common issue with the request lib. You should look into asynchronous requests instead to handle that. Even better, start using scrapy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have hit some kind of IP address limiting. When running the script, it works fine for me without any rate limiting (at the moment). I would though recommend that you make use of `requests.Session()` (you need to change your `requests` variable or it overrides the import). This can help to reduce possible memory leakage issues.

So for example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep
from time import time
from random import randint
import requests

posts = []
votes = []
dates = []
images = []
users = []

start_time = time()
request_count = 0
req_sess = requests.Session()

for page_num in range(1, 100):
    response = req_sess.get(f"https://www.wykop.pl/szukaj/wpisy/smog/strona/{page_num}/")

    # Pause the loop
    #sleep(randint(1,3))

    # Monitor the requests
    request_count += 1
    elapsed_time = time() - start_time
    print('Page {}; Request:{}; Frequency: {} requests/s'.format(page_num, request_count, request_count/elapsed_time))
    
    #clear_output(wait = True)
    # Throw a warning for non-200 status codes
    if response.status_code != 200:
        print('Request: {}; Status code: {}'.format(requests, response.status_code))
        print(response.headers)
    
    # Break the loop if the number of requests is greater than expected
    #if requests > 10:
    #    print('Number of requests was greater than expected.')
    #    break

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    results = soup.find_all('li', class_="entry iC")

    for result in results:
        # Error handling
        try:
            post = result.find('div', class_="text").text
            #post = translate(post,'en','auto')
            posts.append(post)

            date = result.time['title']
            dates.append(date)

            vote = result.p.b.span.text
            vote = int(vote)
            votes.append(vote)

            user = result.div.b.text
            users.append(user)

            image = result.find('img',class_='block lazy')
            images.append(image)

        except AttributeError as e:
            print(e)
```

Gave the following output:

```
Page 1; Request:1; Frequency: 1.246137372973911 requests/s
Page 2; Request:2; Frequency: 1.3021880233774552 requests/s
Page 3; Request:3; Frequency: 1.2663757427416629 requests/s
Page 4; Request:4; Frequency: 1.1807827876080845 requests/s                
.
.
.
Page 96; Request:96; Frequency: 0.8888853607003809 requests/s
Page 97; Request:97; Frequency: 0.8891876183362001 requests/s
Page 98; Request:98; Frequency: 0.888801819672809 requests/s
Page 99; Request:99; Frequency: 0.8900784741536467 requests/s
```

This also worked fine when I started with much higher page numbers. In theory, when you get the 413 error status code, it should now display the response headers. According to [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.11), the server should return a `Retry-After` header field which you could use to determine how long to back off until your next request.

Comment: Hi Martin; worked like a charm! Here's the interesting thing: I think it was the translation module ('post = translate(post,'en','auto')') that was throwing the entire script off. I tried your script with translation muted and active, my presumption was that the latter would slow down the scrapping process, but no! It returned the same 413 error at page 13. That seemed to have been the core of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

OK so here's the catch:

the 413 Error isn't related to Wykop, the website subject to scraping, but to the mtranslate package, which relies on Google Translate's API. In my original code what happened is that as Wykop was scraped, it then translated the posts from Polish to English. However the Google Translation API has a limit of something like 100,000 Characters per 100 seconds per user. So when the code reached the 13th page, mtranslate hit the request limit for *Google Translate*. Hence why Martin's solution works fine scraping the data *with the translate function muted*.

I came to this conclusion as I was using the module to translate the posts stored within the dataframe, as I got hit with the same error at about the 8% mark of my translation loop.